# How to type a react functional component with properties?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

So, I have a react functional component ala....

```
const MyFN = () => {
   // bunch of logic

   MyFN.loaded = someBoolean;

   return <div>just one line</div>
}

MyFN.refresh = () => .......
```

I attached two attributes onto this function,

- loaded
- refresh

How would I type and use it because I am getting errors that

these attributes don't exist on type MyFN?

I tried something like this, but not really working:

```
type MyFN = React.FunctionComponentElement<any> & {loaded: boolean; refresh: Function};
```

Comment: It is rare to do it like this, as it would make component reuse difficult (typically your `loaded` state might be messed up). You might have an XY problem and try doing something that is normally done with `forwardRef`?

Comment: Agree with @ghybs. But just to solve the typing issue - make sure to init all the "static" properties after function declaration https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgcilQ3wFgAoCtCAOwGd4BZATwDEA5OAXjgAoBKbgD44AbwpxJLDgDoANhBQATJEu5wYUAK5IA3BQmSiMLVBpwAPEuAA3IQCstDOLSRw5wGkgsB6a3YoAXwNyaXZ5RRU1HkwUOTo9CjCZImwkOgALdQFhMWDKAup6LAgIdQswuB8hIA

Comment: It's a singleton. Adding properties onto it, are fine. Its a react component, but serves as a control mechanism of sorts.

Answer (score 2):

So you can use an interface like following:

```
interface Props {
  property1: string;
  property2: boolean;
}

const MyFN: React.FC<Props> = ({
  property1,
  property2,
}) => {
  return <div>{property1}</div>
}
```